# Chaining getDocument with Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
user
  29384092840923
     chatRoomsJoined
         chatRoom1
         chatroom5

chatrooms
   chatRoom1 
      users 
         29384092840923
         298340982039490
```

I'm trying to load a tableview with information about the chat rooms a user has joined into. In the case above, user "29384092840923" has joined into chatRoom1, and I need the count of children of the users node in chatRoom1

My initial strat was to get an array of the joinedChatRooms from the "user" node and then do a for loop through and do a getDocument on each of the items in the array.

```
 static func loadFavoriteRooms(forUID uid: String, completedFetch: @escaping (_ favoritedRoomsArray : [String]?, _ error : Error?)->()) {

      let userFavoritesRef = database.collection("users").document(uid).collection("favoritedRooms")
      userFavoritesRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            completedFetch(nil, error!)
            print("There was an error", error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            var roomArray = [String]()
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                //Create a roomRef with the documentID, do a getDocument with it, and create an object with it? 
                let roomName = document.documentID
                roomArray.append(roomName)
            }
           completedFetch(roomArray, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

My problem with what happened above was once I started sending off additional getDocument requests within the for-loop for the individual roomRefs, my completedFetch completion call was returning before the for loop was done asynchronously, and I wasn't getting a filled array back.

What's the cleanest way to do this? Do I need to do a dispatch group here or is there a better way to accomplish this? Using dispatch groups with firestore seems wrong here to me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option could be to use a [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup). Something like -

```
var roomArray = [String]()

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for document in snapshot!.documents {

    let roomId = document.documentID
    let roomRef = database.collection("rooms").document(roomId)

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    roomRef.getDocument { (roomSnapshot, error) in
        // Create the room from the snapshot here
        roomArray.append(roomName)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    completedFetch(roomArray, nil)
})
```

Just make sure you got your `.enter()` and `.leave()` calls correct otherwise you'll get some very strange crashes.

Comment: Thanks a ton Chris. Appreciate it!